# Pageable not doing pagination after upgrade to spring boot 3 with db2 db

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, db2

After application was updated to springboot 3.0.6 from 2.5 server side pagination is not working.
I am passing a pageable object to findAll() method of jpaRepository, the pageable object contains size, number and sort. The sort is working fine but not returning in pages it is returning all the data. Hiberante 6.1 is used and DB2 is used as a database. Doesnt shows any error seems it is ignoring the pagination.

Tried changing the hibernate and jpa versions but did not worked.

Comment: As you didn't provide any source code, I can only guess: You have to add PagingAndSortingRepository to your existing repository (e.g. `implements JpaRepository<Type, Id>, PagingAndSortingRepository(Type, Id>`).

Comment: the existing code does not have this, i am using findAll(id, Pageable). Do i need to add PagingAndSortingRepository(Type, Id> because even without this it was working fine only after the upgrade it is breaking.